# months between two dates in sql server with starting and end date of each of them in sql server with end date could be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get months between two dates with their starting and end dates. Suppose if i enter startdate as "07/06/2019" and enddate as "18/09/2019", i want list the months in between with their starting and end date respectively.Kindly suggest me how it can be achieved. Also if the End Date Utc is null then it should automatically split the dates upto the current date i.e. 19/09/19

Input Table (BusinessGoal):

```
BusinessRefId   Period  GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc      EndDateUtc         Currency
Business C      Year    CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/07/19 00:00:00 19/09/19 00:00:00  USD
```

Output Table (BusinessGoal):

```
BusinessRefId   Period              GoalType                Amount  StartDateUtc         EndDateUtc           Currency
Business C      2019-07 - 2019-08   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/07/2019 00:00:00  05/08/2019 00:00:00    USD
Business C      2019-08 - 2019-09   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/08/2019 00:00:00  05/09/2019 00:00:00    USD
Business C      2019-09 - 2019-10   CommittedTransactionFee 18000   05/09/2019 00:00:00  05/10/2019 00:00:00    USD
```

I have already written a query which split the dates according to yearly i.e if the BusinessGoal.Period = 'Year'

```
declare @BusinessGoal table  
(BusinessRefId varchar(50),   
Period varchar(50), 
GoalType varchar(100),    
Amount money, 
StartDateUtc datetime,   
EndDateUtc datetime, 
Currency varchar(10));

insert into @BusinessGoal values
  ('Business A', 'Year', 'CommittedTransactionFee', 45000, '2019-06-07 00:00:00', NULL, 'USD'),
  ('Business B', 'Year', 'CommittedTransactionFee', 18000, '2017-06-07 00:00:00', NULL, 'USD'),
  ('Business E', 'Year', 'CommittedTransactionFee', 5000 , '2019-04-01 00:00:00', '2019-08-01 00:00:00', 'USD');

select BusinessRefId 
  , cast(ys.y as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(ys.y + 1 as varchar(4))  Period
  , GoalType, Amount
  , dateadd(year, nmbs.n, tbl.StartDateUtc) StartDateUtc
  , case when ys.NextDate > tbl.EndDateUtc then tbl.EndDateUtc else ys.NextDate end EndDateUtc
  , Currency
from @BusinessGoal tbl
join 
(values (0),(1),(2)
 ) nmbs(n)
on dateadd(year, nmbs.n, tbl.StartDateUtc) <= getdate() 
  and (EndDateUtc is null or EndDateUtc >= datefromparts(Year(tbl.StartDateUtc) + nmbs.n + 1, 1, 1))
cross apply (select Year(tbl.StartDateUtc) + nmbs.n y, dateadd(year, nmbs.n + 1,tbl.StartDateUtc) NextDate) ys
```

I have to integrate the splitting of dates by "Month" and "Year" by implementing a check on BusinessGoal table Period column i.e
if BusinessGoal.Period = 'Year' and if BusinessGoal.Period = 'Month'.

Comment: Create a recursive CTE that will generate a sequence of incrementing integers starting with 0, join it to your data, DATEADD the incrementing integer to the start date with "months" as the interval. COALESCE(enddate, getutcdate()) to make the end date the current day if it's null. Use a where clause to look for rows between your desired dates. (This is pretty much what you have, except it works on a months interval rather than years and generates more rows)

Comment: @CaiusJard i have to integrate it in the existing query i mentioned in the question above.

Comment: OK, so do the months form too - make the where clause you have already examine if 'Year' is passed in and do that where clause OR (another similar where clause that looks if months is passed in and dateadd(months) instead of years). You might find it easier to do two queries, one that doesthe years and only works on WHERE business goal = year, and then union another query on that only does months and businessgoal = months

Comment: @CaiusJard i don't know how to create a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to write the recursive CTE proposed by Caius Jard on the comments :

```
-- Create a Test Table
select '2019-07-05' as StartDateUtc, '2019-09-19' as EndDateUtc
into #test;

-- Recursive CTE that returns the months between StartDateUtc and EndDateUtc
with months as (
  -- initial values of the recursive CTE
  select datefromparts(year(StartDateUtc), month(StartDateUtc), 1) as StartPeriod,
         dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(StartDateUtc), month(StartDateUtc), 1)) as EndPeriod,
         t.StartDateUtc, t.EndDateUtc
  from #test t
  union all
  -- we recursively add 1 month until we reach EndDateUtc
  select dateadd(month, 1, StartPeriod) as StartPeriod,
         dateadd(month, 1, EndPeriod) as EndPeriod,
         months.StartDateUtc, months.EndDateUtc
  from months 
  where dateadd(month, 1, StartPeriod) <= coalesce(EndDateUtc, StartDateUtc)  -- If EndDateUtc is null then we use StartDateUtc, so only the first month is returned
)
select * from months;

-- Drop Test Table
drop table #test;
```